# Check if application was closed by exit or by the system error or something

Tags: vb.net

I would like to check the way which determined application was closed. Are any methods to check if application was closed properly by X or by the system error or something in vb.net?

Comment: where will You check how it was closed? Inside application?

Comment: Assuming a windows forms application, the `FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason` and `FormClosedEventArgs.CloseReason` property contains an enumeration of possible reasons a form is closing/closed. You could query this in a `FormClosing` or `FormClosed` event handler. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException is never really optional, you need to tell the user why your program crashed.  And you get the extra benefit, you can always tell when your program terminates abnormally.

Comment: I will check in the supervisor application another applications.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this at 3 levels:

1. For the close events that were caused by VB.NET (your code that is), you should introduce a central place for handling application shutdown. Therein, you can set some flag, such as a disk file or reg entry that would tell you that the application was closed through the code.
2. For exceptions, you can introduce an application-level unhandled exception handler wherein you can again set your flag. For handled exceptions, your catch blocks should adopt a similar policy.
3. For the **Close** button or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> stuff, you can handle your main form's (or `Window`'s; don't know which platform you're using) `Closing` event and mark the file flag therein. This event provides additional information about the close reason that might be helpful for you.